# How can I generate random strings in TSQL

Tags: t-sql

How can I generate a random string? 
I wrote the following, which gave my only one letter as a result !

```
declare @alphaCount int
set @alphaCount =  @alphaCount +1
CHAR(@alphaCount)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SQL is a domain specific query langauge, not a full fledged programming language. generate random string on the client, not on the db side.

Comment: I want to fill my dataBase with data!!

Comment: What type of random string do you need? (length and acceptable characters)

Comment: length 20, acceptable characters A-Z a-z

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will give you 10,000 rows in the specified format.

```
DECLARE @Numbers  TABLE
(
n INT PRIMARY KEY
);


WITH E00(N) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),   --2
        E02(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E00 a, E00 b), --4
        E04(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E02 a, E02 b), --16
        E08(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E04 a, E04 b), --256
        E16(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E08 a, E08 b)  --65,536
INSERT INTO @Numbers
SELECT TOP 10000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0))
FROM E16        

SELECT CAST((SELECT TOP 20 CHAR(CASE
                                  WHEN Abs(Checksum(Newid()))%2 = 0 THEN 65
                                  ELSE 97
                                END + Abs(Checksum(Newid()))%26)
             FROM   @Numbers n1
             WHERE  n1.n >= -n2.n /*So it gets re-evaluated for each row!*/
             FOR XML PATH('')) AS CHAR(20))
FROM   @Numbers n2
```

Answer (score 1):

Fill a temporary table with a list of random words. Then use CROSS JOIN to combine every word with every other word, to get a whole ton of data with little effort.

```
select l.word+' '+r.word from #Words as l
cross join #Words as r
```

Comment: How can I generate list of random words?

Comment: @Shaza, just make some up! The cross join will generate the square of the number of inputs you give it. If you feed it 20 words, it will generate 400 combinations. If you feed it 1000 words, it will generate 1000000.

Answer (score 1):

[This procedure](http://www.brettb.com/SQL_Help_Random_Strings.asp) will work.  You may have to create a function with it, but it has the right ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for how to

```
DECLARE @length         Integer
DECLARE @return         VarChar(1000)
DECLARE @index          Integer
DECLARE @value          Integer

SET @length = 12
SET @return = '';

IF @length > 1000
    SET @length = 1000;

IF @length <= 0
    SELECT @return;

SET @index = 0;

WHILE @index < @length
BEGIN
    SET @value = (64 * RAND()) + 32;
    SET @return = @return + CHAR(@value);

    SET @index = @index + 1;
END 

SELECT @return;
```

If you wanted to make this a user defined function, i liked the option 'steve' had in this article. [here](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.sqlserver.programming/browse_thread/thread/2fe4d7a06001cde9/6bc1a4f539b567a4?pli=1)