# How to update the data in a specific column with random data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 1000's of records. I want to update a specific column with pure string values. I have referred some previous questions and I got this:

```
DECLARE @LENGTH INT = 4;
UPDATE bbvasample SET [Agency Name]=
  SUBSTRING(REPLACE(CAST(NEWID() AS character(255)),'-',''), 1, @LENGTH)
```

When I work it out, I got data combinations of string and integers, so I want pure string data. I am new so excuse mistakes, if any. Thanks in adv :)

Comment: Tag the dbms used, product specific SQL involved. (Perhaps SQL Server?)

Comment: there are many articles out there on populating with random data....

Comment: and who's to say an agency name can't contain a numeral?  "Level 7 Widgets"

Comment: @jarlh Yes I am using sql server

Comment: @MitchWheat Agency name is just a sample,I am gonna use it for user name.

Comment: Check out Martin Smith's answer to [this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558403/how-can-i-generate-random-strings-in-tsql)

Comment: @ZoharPeled so where to mention my existing table name and column there ?

Comment: That answer is on how to create random strings in sql-server, you can adapt it to your needs but it will have to write the update statement. I currently don't have the time to write a proper answer, perhaps later today.